# Make breadcrumb from multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
          [id] => 68
          [cat_name] => Business Insurance
          [cat_slug] => business-insurance
          [is_parent] => 67
          [parent] => Array
                   (
                      [0] => Array
                          (
                             [id] => 67
                             [cat_name] => Insurance
                             [cat_slug] => insurance
                             [is_parent] => 65
                             [parent] => Array
                                      (
                                         [0] => Array
                                             (
                                                [id] => 65
                                                [cat_name] => Finance and Investment
                                                [cat_slug] => finance-and-investment
                                                [is_parent] => 47
                                                [parent] => Array
                                                          (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                 (
                                                                   [id] => 47
                                                                [cat_name] => Business & Economy
                                                                [cat_slug] => business-economy
                                                                [is_parent] => 0
                                  )
                              )
                          )
                      )
                  )
             )
       )
)
```

I need a recursive function for Codeignitor which will show the above array as Business & Economy -> Finance and Investment -> Insurance -> Business Insurance as the breadcrumb. Please help.

Comment: You want the deepest crumb to be listed first?

Comment: Can you please add the `PHP` original arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't check it, it might work

```
function processArray($config) {
    $firstElement = $config[0];
    $result = '';
    if (isset($firstElement['parent'])) {
        $result .= processArray($firstElement['parent']) . ' / ';
    }
    $result .= $firstElement['cat_name']; // Probably want to wrap it in a-tag with href
    return $result;
}
```

updated: to get the first element

Comment: I've tested the function and its working, [sandbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2f45b208048279bb08183adb59fd83d26aac1f9)

Comment: Each `parent` contains only a single array, it looks like your code does not account for this. (e.g `$config['parent']` should be `$config[0]['parent']`)

Comment: ive updated my answer, but this is a minor change, and as already mentioned i didnt check it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursion loop like this, which will create an array of breadcrumbs.

```
function breadcrumb_recursion($arr, $crumbs = []) {
    $arr = $arr[0];
    if (!empty($arr['parent'])) {
        $crumbs = breadcrumb_recursion($arr['parent']);
    }
    $crumbs[] = $arr['cat_name'];
    return $crumbs;
}
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Business & Economy
    [1] => Finance and Investment
    [2] => Insurance
    [3] => Business Insurance
)
```

Now, you can easily echo this on your page by using `implode()`.

```
echo implode(' / ', $breadcrumb_return);
```

Result

```
Business & Economy / Finance and Investment / Insurance / Business Insurance
```